# Sklearn how to get the 10 words from each topic

Tags: python, matrix, tf-idf

I want to get the top 10 frequency of words from each topic, and after I use TfidfTransformer, I get: and the type is scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

But I don't know how to get the highest ten from each list, in the data, (0, ****) means the 0 list, until (5170, *****) means the 5170 list.

I've tried to convert it into numpy, but it fails.

```
  (0, 19016)    0.024214182003181053
  (0, 28002)    0.03661443306612277
  (0, 6710) 0.02292100371816788
  (0, 27683)    0.013973969726506812
  (0, 27104)    0.02236713272585597
  (0, 6889) 0.0403281034949193
.
.
.
 (5169, 3236)   0.014432449220428715
  (5169, 19134) 0.014346823328868169
  (5169, 32915) 0.002047199186262409
  (5170, 35899) 0.49931779368675605
  (5170, 36444) 0.3479717717856863
  (5170, 15014) 0.5608169649159123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TfidfVectorizer` to expose the `get_feature_names` method. The transformer doesn't have this method, but the docs clearly state that the `Vectorizer` is equivalent to `CountVectorizer` followed by the transformer. If you don't want to use this, then I think you're going to be stuck building a lookup before you vectorize.

TfidfVectorizer in the docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Edit: to sort and slice the output of `fit_transform` from the `TfidfVectorizer` normal sparse matrix operations should work.