# How to get top 10 words from each category in dataframe with 10,000+ entries?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Alright, Im following https://medium.com/@phylypo/text-classification-with-scikit-learn-on-khmer-documents-1a395317d195 , working w a dataframe laid out like this and named `result`:

```
target   type    post
    1      intj    "hello world shdjd"
    2      entp    "hello world fddf"
    16     estj   "hello world dsd"
    4      esfp    "hello world sfs"
    1      intj    "hello world ddfd"
```

Each post is unique, and target just assigns number 1-16 to each of the 16 types or categories. I want to use sklearn to find the top words per each of the 16 types.

I know you can use TfidfTransformer to get the top words of a corpus and looked at [Sklearn how to get the 10 words from each topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53193422/sklearn-how-to-get-the-10-words-from-each-topic) , however I dont know how exactly this plays out w a dataframe.

```
def get_top_n_words(corpus, n=None):
        vec = CountVectorizer().fit(corpus)
        bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
        sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)
        words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
        words_freq = sorted(words_freq, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        return words_freq[:n]
    
    print(get_top_n_words(result.post, 10))
```

This got me the top 10 of all posts, however did not remove stop words like "this" or "and", and **did not categorize by type.** How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Categorizing part :

you can create a dictionary to map each topic to his data, then get top n words to each topic in the dictionary, for example:

```py
# just for exmaple
corpus_dict = {"topic1": "data1", "topic2": "data2"}
# top n words dict
top_n_words_dict = {}
# iterate overall topics inside the corpus
# inorder to get top n words for each topic
for topic in corpus_dict.keys(): 
    # map the topic to the top n words in the topic
    top_n_words_dict[topic] = get_top_n_words(corpus_dict[topic], 10)
    # print for test purposes 
    print(f"Topic: {topic}, top 10 words: {top_n_words_dict[topic]}")
```

Don't focus in the code, focus in the idea.

#### Stop words part :

you can use `nltk` lib to get all English stop words:

```py
import nltk

# get set of english stop words
stop_words = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english"))
```

then you can filter your words before calculating words frequency.

Comment: Right, but my dataframe has over 10,000 entries. How can I do this efficiently, for each  of the 16 types? There are many many posts for each type

Comment: Filter your words when you're tokenizing them.

Comment: right, however that still doesnt answer my question. I dont know how to sort top words per each TYPE - the stop words really arent the main problem.

Comment: Thank you. But you need to understand how large this dataframe is and that a dictionary is not an efficient/feasible approach. I need a method that can handle tens of thousands of posts